# Keyboard dismissed as soon as presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an app which involves using different kinds of Gestures. So, in order to differentiate between thse gestures, I used `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` method which returns a YES. However, on doing this the keyboard on the `UIWebView` is dismissed right after it is being presented. And if I don't then the keyboard functions correctly but the controller fails to recognize different gestures. 
     How do I make the keyboard function correctly and at the same time recognize different gestures ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate Methods

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

//You can use like this in your   shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer  method
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: the issue is to dismissing keyboard in the case of webView.